# Push notification in android using deacon

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to implement push notifications on my application. I want to push directly from my servers, and thus cant use Google's C2DM or Xtify.. 
I learnt about the deacon project, but facing problems using it.
Firstly, my complete project is in Windows, and the Meteor server runs only in linux.. is there any work around?

Comment: nopes.. still looking for a way to run meteor server on windows. It works fine on linux though..

Comment: Actually I dont know how to customize the meteor server for sending push notifications to some android devices? Could u please suggest some tutorial for it?

Comment: Hi, i found in this website http://www.abolkog.com/portal/java-programming/117-android-push-notifications that, u have sucessfully installed the Meteor server, and ur Meteor server is running successfully. Please tell me how could u install the sever? I am also using Winows OS

Comment: i used the same tutorial. I installed meteor server on a linux machine and am calling it from my android code. However, I am still not able to get the app running. Some network issues.. working on that

Comment: Thanks for the help. Whether this server can send push notification whenever we pool the message to server or will it push messages periodically as shown in the demo?

Comment: it totally depends on you. the demo has a periodic '2sec' channel that sends notifications every 2 secondsa. You can define your channel the way you want

Comment: Hi , pls share the solution of how to use meteor on windows ? And also tell how to test app on linux using localhost.